# Crontab absolute path not working

Tags: cron

I have a script to backup my database at `/home/<user>/bin/dbbackup`. The script is executable by all users, and owned by me. The files `/etc/cron.allow` and `/etc/cron.deny` do not exist.

In my `crontab` I have the following lines (including a new blank line after the last line of code):

```
@reboot /home/<user>/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd

30 2 * * * bash /home/<user>/bin/dbbackup
```

However, cron is not running my `dbbackup` script. When I run a manual test of the script it works. When I run this test on the command line: `* * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> ~/file` I get the following error:

```
No command 'dbbackup' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dvbackup' from package 'dvbackup' (universe)
 Command 'tdbbackup' from package 'tdb-tools' (main)
dbbackup: command not found
```

My server is running Ubuntu Trusty. Any help please?

Comment: So `* * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> ~/file` produces a `"dbbackup" command not found` error? Sounds weird.

Comment: So cron is running running the job under your user account?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this works, but I found online that `* * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> ~/file` from the command line can be used to test whether cron is working (makes sense), but I've discovered that it also fails on problems with items in the crontab that are scheduled for specific times (which doesn't make sense to me). I, like I imagine many others, am really just trying to do some web programming in php with a database, and want to use cron as a backup solution. I've found it non-intuitive to say the least.

Comment: Try using the full path to bash. I usually just call scripts from location and use "#!/bin/bash" (or wherever yours lives) as the first line. Cron executes as the user but does not read your bash profile and therefore does not work exactly like it would under your shell as it might not have access to your $PATH.

Comment: Van Amburg—All my scripts have bash at the top also. I only added the call to bash into crontab, as I read online that it had worked for someone else. Strangely, if I put the full path to bash in crontab (`/bin/bash`), I get the error `No command 'bin' found...`. However, removing the call to bash from crontab now seems to result in the cron test running successfully from the command line—including running the line of code in crontab scheduled for 2:30am (not behaviour I expect, but there you go). Finally... I just reset the time for the crontab line for a few minutes later to test it...

Comment: ...and it works! So... if you re-write your comment suggesting that I remove bash from the crontab as an answer, then I'll mark it as correct. Cheers Van Amburg! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments noted, it appears that amiga_os needed remove the reference to bash in the line.

```
30 2 * * * bash /home/<user>/bin/dbbackup
```

Should be.

```
30 2 * * * /home/<user>/bin/dbbackup
```

I usually just call scripts from their path and use "#!/bin/bash" (or wherever your bash lives) as the first line of the script. It appears the amiga_os had already done this, which is good. I don't like putting sentences into cron because it makes me nervous.

I think it was a path issue as cron executes as the user but does not read the bash profile and therefore does not work exactly like it would under your shell as it might not have access to your $PATH.